# Issue with text animation in HTML and CSS slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on creating a slideshow using HTML and CSS, and I've encountered an issue with animating the text on each slide. While I've successfully implemented the slideshow functionality itself, I've been struggling to make the text animation work as expected. The problem I'm facing is that the animation only seems to work on the first text element of the first slide, and not on subsequent slides or text elements.

This is my code:

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.slider .slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  animation: slider 17.5s infinite;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595356700395-6f14b5c1f33f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80');
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591019052241-e4d95a5dc3fc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80');
  animation-delay: -3.5s;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543373014-cfe4f4bc1cdf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80');
  animation-delay: -7s;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517430554953-a5ba4678fe85?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80');
  animation-delay: -10.5s;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(5) {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583161178154-c362b3459d29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80');
  animation-delay: -14s;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0%,
  11%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    animation-timing-function: ease;
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    animation-timing-function: step-end;
  }
  91% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    animation-timing-function: ease;
  }
}

.slider-title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: fit-content;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.slider-subtitle {
  background-color: black;
  width: fit-content;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.slide-in-left {
  animation: slideLeft 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-in-right {
  animation: slideRight 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}


/* Definirea animației pentru slide-in-left */

@keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}


/* Definirea animației pentru slide-in-right */

@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <p class="slider-title slide-in-left">discover OUR portofolio</p>
    <p class="slider-subtitle slide-in-right">YEAR OF EXPERIENCE IN THE PHOTO INDUSTRY</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <p class="slider-title slide-in-left">Featured design project</p>
    <p class="slider-subtitle slide-in-right">PHOTOGRAPHY, ART DIRECTOR AND MORE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <p class="slider-title">true beauty and style</p>
    <p class="slider-subtitle">LETS COLLABORATE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <p class="slider-title">welcome to SON photography</p>
    <p class="slider-subtitle">CLICK TO DISCOVER THE WORLD OF SHANE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <p class="slider-title">ok, it's time to click on menu</p>
    <p class="slider-subtitle">LETS CLICK</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have two options: Either build the animation with javascript, OR you use an animation loop that gets delayed per slide. The second option requires some mathematics for it to work properly.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work, that's why I asked for help here.

Comment: You should probably mark your active slide with a class, and only add your animations to slides with that class. As it stands now, all those animations get executed once on page load due to CSS being applicable from the very first moment.